# Oracle-SQL Correlated Subquery in UPDATE-Statement doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update, correlated-subquery

what's wrong with my following statement:

```
UPDATE TableToUpdate SET ColumnToUpdate = (
    SELECT ColumnWithNewValues
    FROM (
        SELECT ColumnWithNewValues, ROWNUM AS N
        FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2       -- join tables
        WHERE t2.Schluessel = t1.Schluessel -- join condition
        AND t1.DateFrom <= TableToUpdate.Date   -- <==== Error, reference to TableToUpdate
        AND t1.DatumTo >= TableToUpdate.Date
        -- ... some other conditions, not important here ... 
    ) tmp
    WHERE tmp.N = 5         -- Use the fifth row to update the row of TableToUpdate
)
```

On execution of this i will get an error from oracle:

```
ORA-00904: "TableToUpdate"."Date": Ungültiger Bezeichner
```

In english i think this would mean:

```
ORA-00904: "TableToUpdate"."Date": Invalid identifier
```

So it seems that i can't reference to the TableToUpdate from a correlated subquery in the SELECT-Statement. Under MSSQL this works while replacing the oracle specific ROWNUM with
an equivalent technology of course.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring from within your subquery, two levels deep, to the outermost table. The restriction is that you can only refer one level up. Hence the error message.

You can circumvent this restriction by rewriting your update statement to a merge statement. For example, untested, like this:

```
merge into tabletoupdate t
using ( select datefrom
             , datumto
             , ColumnWithNewValues
          from ( select t1.datefrom
                      , t1.datumto
                      , ColumnWithNewValues
                      , rownum as n
                   from table1 t1
                        inner join table2 t2 on (t2.Schluessel = t1.Schluessel) -- join condition
                --where ... some other conditions, not important here ... 
                --order by ... some columns here, otherwise rownum is meaningless
               ) tmp
         where tmp.n =5         -- Use the fifth row to update the row of TableToUpdate
      )
   on (   t1.DateFrom <= t.Date
      and t1.DatumTo >= t.Date
      )
 when matched then
      update set t.columntoupdate = tmp.columnwithnewvalues
```